# show data in by id in foreach php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I display item data, in the data there is an id, I want to display a list of data based on that id
[image]

this my code

```
foreach ($list as $datas) {
            $detail = $this->M_master->get_byid($datas->id)->result();
            // foreach($detail as $v){
            //  $row[] = $v->barang;
            // }
            $row = array();
            $no++;
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $detail; //how to show data looping wehre id ?
            $row[] = $datas->name;
            $row[] = $datas->description;
            $row[] = $datas->location_name;
            $row[] = '<div class="btn-group">
            <a href=""><span type="button" class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: -6px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 20px;">attach_file</span></a>
        </div>';
        $data[] = $row;
    }
 
    $output = array(
                "draw" => intval($_POST["draw"]),
                "recordsTotal" => $this->M_master->count_all(),
                "recordsFiltered" => $this->M_master->count_filtered(),
                "data" => $data,
            );
    echo json_encode($output);
```

/how to show data looping wehre id ?

Comment: var_dump $detail what does it give you?

Comment: $detail is array , how to show ?

Comment: $row[] = $detail['id'];

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can do all inside your foreach/for

```
$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
            
    $data[$i]['no'] = $i +1; //no stars in 1
    $data[$i]['details'] = $this->M_master->get_byid($datas->id)->result();                
    $data[$i]['name'] = $datas->name;
    $data[$i]['description'] = $datas->description;
    $data[$i]['location_name'] = $datas->location_name;
    //dont put the button because no sense, better you can just write the url
    $data[$i]['url'] = 'https://urlhere.dom/whateveryouwant';
}

$output = array();
$output['draw'] = intval($_POST["draw"]);
$output['recordsTotal'] = $this->M_master->count_all();
$output['recordsFiltered'] = $this->M_master->count_filtered();
$output['data'] = $data;


echo json_encode($output, true); //True for go key-value
```

Now, when you are reading just need go object.key.
(example in javascript)

```
YourgetData.forEach(element => console.log(element.draw, element.data.id, element.data.name, element.data.url));
```

Comment: Where is `$output` declared in your snippet?  Why is `$row` declared?

Comment: Sorry about `$row`, its a copy-paste mistake. Will upload the answer to contains same as `$output`

Comment: your current snippet keeps overwriting the data inside the loop (it's flatly incorrect)

Comment: Yh, in the edit i correct that